# If else for a new column

Tags: r

can anyone help point out which symbol is wrong in the codes?

**Question:**
create a new column named Postion_new from the old column Position. For further analyses, we want to bring that variable to a higher level, namely: “Goalkeeper”, “Defense”, “Midfield” and “Offense”. Assign the positions as follows:

– Defense: “Right Fullback”, “Left Fullback”, “Center Back”, “Defensive Midfielder”

– Midfield: “Right Midfielder”, “Left Midfielder”, “Center Midfielder”

– Offense: “Attacking Midfielder”, “Right Winger”, “Left Winger”, “Center Forward”

So I used the ifelse formate above, but it turned out error for the first line

> 'unexpected symbol in "df$position_new<-ifelse(df$position %in% c("Right Fullback”, “Left Fullback”, “Center Back”, “Defensive Midfielder”), yes = "Defense"'. Which symbol is wrong?

**My code:**

```
df$position_new<-ifelse(df$position %in% c("Right Fullback”, “Left Fullback”, “Center Back”, “Defensive Midfielder”), yes = "Defense",

ifelse(df$position %in% c(“Right Midfielder”, “Left Midfielder”, “Center Midfielder”), yes = “Midfield”,

ifelse(df$position %in% c(“Attacking Midfielder”, “Right Winger”, “Left Winger”, “Center Forward”), yes = "Offense", no = “Goalkeeper” ))))
```

Comment: Some of your quotes are "smart quotes", `”` and `“`. In coding, you need to use regular quotes `"`. This sometimes happen if you copy paste from a document in Word or Google Docs that automatically replaces regular quotes with smart quotes.

Comment: Note that you can see the issue here due to Stack Overflow's code formatting. The strings between quotes should be one color, different from the rest of the code.

Comment: yes exactly I could see the color difference but I could not figure out why, thanks for pointing out!